# Internet explorer 9 problems with drawing video on canvs HTML5

Tags: html, canvas, internet-explorer-9, html5-video

I'm drawing video on canvas and it works in opera, mozilla and chrome but in IE9 canvas is blank but video is playing. Here is javascript that I'm using: [code](http://pastebin.com/tAi8AvpP)

Thanks for your help

Comment: What format is your video? What exceptions, if any, do you see in the F12 Script Console?

Comment: Error: Unable to get value of the property 'paused': object is null or undefined

Comment: My videos are in mp4 and ogg. Video is playing fine in IE9 just canvas is blank.

Comment: Ok I resolved the 'paused' issue. Now I get: "SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'drawImage': object is null or undefined" to me it looks like the problem might be with context. The error is on this line:"c.drawImage(v, 0, 0, w, h);"

Answer (score 0):

You probably should sync the **playing** event rather than the **play** event. If you try to access a video before any frames are loaded, you'll get a null reference. The play event fires when playback is *requested*. The playing event fires when playback actually begins.

You also might want to move your getContext call to AFTER where you've resized the canvas.

Comment: But *how* did you fix the problem?

Comment: I avoided syncing with events and I just start video in javascript before I draw it on canvas (   video.play(); )

Answer (score 0):

The code below seems to work for me. The only change is the setTimeout function call needs to have a wrapper in order to pass the parameters correctly in IE. The demos at http://html5doctor.com/video-canvas-magic/ seem to work fine with this change.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    var v = document.getElementById('video');
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

    var cw = Math.floor(canvas.clientWidth);
    var ch = Math.floor(canvas.clientHeight);
    canvas.width = cw;
    canvas.height = ch;

    v.addEventListener('play', function () {
        draw(this, context, cw, ch);
    }, false);

}, false);

function draw(v, c, w, h) {
    if (v.paused || v.ended) return false;
    c.drawImage(v, 0, 0, w, h);
    setTimeout(function(){ draw(v, c, w, h) }, 20);
}​
```